# User with less than 3k reputation just cast a reopen vote

Tags: bug, status-completed, privileges, vote-to-reopen

**[Exhibit A](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/24585677/revisions)**:

> [image]

**[Exhibit B](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2963652/nicael?tab=reputation)**:

> [image]

Also no bounties in those minutes etc.

What the... ?

**Edit**: I am able to reproduce it myself.

> [image]

Developer who want to know how I did it, so they can seal the loophole can contact me in private.

Comment: Sigh, has he found another loophole somewhere perhaps?

Comment: @nicael the Reopen link should not be visible if you don't have 3K rep.  Did you hack the link to get to the reopen dialong?  Or did you see the reopen link under the question?

Comment: I've contacted @ShadowWizard in private to procure repro steps. Then I'll patch.

Comment: No, do NOT post anything indicating how you've done this please. At least not until I've patched it.

Comment: I was able to replicate this on Programmers: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/17731/chris -- here is the question: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/247074

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Thanks to the help of **Shadow Wizard**, I have patched this loophole in our security. The fix will be live in the next prod build (> rev `2014.7.3.2354`).

All of us at Stack Exchange are huge fans of transparency and openness, but we have chosen not to reveal the details of this exploit. The reasoning is that it would likely stir a "witch hunt" of users trying to exploit many areas of our site, which isn't what we desire to have happen.

**We always appreciate and are thankful for the support of folks like Shadow Wizard who white-hat security holes to us in private (via e-mail for example).**

Comment: Tomorrow I'll find a hole and suspend you (for security reasons). And, by the way, will you give 200,000 reps to Sha?

Comment: ah, the good ole security through obscurity technique ;D

Comment: @ShadowWizard wants 200000 rep, I started counter-negotiations at -200000 rep, and we met in the middle. But I owe him a coke (or beer).

Comment: @DaveHaney I'll be happy with the unicorn doll you have [here](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/company/stack-exchange). :D

Comment: On a serious note @Dave, can't you push a build for this? Any decent programmer can easily guess how to do this and I'm quite sure you got a bunch of "false" reopen votes in those last few hours.

Comment: @ShadowWizard We're waiting on some maintenance on the build machines to be completed.

Comment: @AnnaLear thanks, just don't let it grow to 6-8 weeks plz.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Aw, but moooooooom...

Comment: Cheers, confirmed it's fixed. :)

Comment: nope its not fixed yet i think

Comment: before reach 3k it shows in notification http://i.stack.imgur.com/mqhSz.png

Comment: @Haney can you tell me about notification issue

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan it looks as though you reached 3000 and were awarded the privilege, but shortly after received -2 points (perhaps for a downvote). Once you hit the bar, dipping back below it doesn't revoke the privilege.

Comment: if i get any minus 2 then it supposed to show in my repo..

Comment: @AdityaVyas-Lakhan dunno, create a new meta post and we'll try and take a look!